# How to apply multiple styles to one object in Adobe Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, object-styles

For example I have defined two styles named "position: absolute" and "width: auto". Now I want to apply them separately to two objects, and both on third object. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: That is not an option in InDesign. You will have to create separate object styles for each combination.

Comment: As Jongware stated. This is not how Indesign works. I believe you are coming form CSS experience which doesn't apply in Indesign!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two styles at the same time, but you can combine them to get similar effect, for example

Style 1 - "Postion to 10mm from left page margin" only moves the object

Style 2 - "Apply drop shadow"

Style 3 - "Object width 30 mm"

Style 4 - "My Special Style"

Order in which you'd apply them would matter if they overlap or change each other's parameters, if they're not overlapping they will work independently.

Also only **one** can be applied at any point in time - so which ever one you'll likely be changing for the whole document - keep that one!

For further discussion how this might apply to grapic styles see https://indesignsecrets.com/tip-of-the-week-using-more-than-one-object-style-to-format-an-object.php